# Possible to pull random entry from array and keep schedule?

Tags: php, arrays, schedule

Not sure if this is possible with just php or if I'd need something else too. Basically I'd like to have an array with a bunch of entries, such as:

(1234,5432,5678,5899,3245)

And I'd like to have the php randomly select one entry from the array AND stick to that entry it selected for 3 days. So for example, on a given date, it would pull "5432" from the array, then it would hold that entry for 3 days, then after 3 days it would pick another entry and hold it for 3 days, etc.

Any ideas how this could be done? Can it be done with just php? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Have you  tried some code ?

Comment: PHP is not particularly persistent. How do you plan on "maintaining" a value for longer than the duration of the script, i.e. 3 days?

Comment: You will need a php script that collects the array, selects an element and stores it. You will also need a persistent store. In the most basic of implementations, you could use `array_rand` to select a random element, then store that element (or key to that element) in a text file using `fopen` and `fwrite`. Any script that requires that random element should read the text file you write to, in order to get the data. You would then set up a crontab to execute the php "get random element" script every 3 days, to refresh the stored/cached element. (of course this is a very basic way of doing it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a PHP program (command line), and not running a script on a web server you can run this script to stay on all the time and wait to draw.

```
$entries = array( 34534, 435, 345 );

while(1) {

    // subtract 1 from total number of entries because arrays start at an index of 0.
    $totalNumberOfEntries = sizeof( $entries ) - 1;

    // if no entries left, quit the program
    if ($totalNumberOfEntries <= 0) break;

    // grab a random index from your array using `mt_rand()` function
    $entry = $entries[ mt_rand(0, $totalNumberOfEntries - 1) ];

    // write the entry to a file
    file_put_contents( 'entry.txt', $entry, FILE_APPEND );

    // wait 3 days to draw again
    sleep( 3600 * 24 * 3 );

}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I am indeed just running the script on a web server. I'm very new to this stuff, major apologies! Can this code work on a web server if I just upload an empty .txt file etc.?

Comment: No. If you have cPanel you can setup a cron job, and ditch the `while`  loop and `sleep`. Then from the server you can obtain the entry from the database or the `entry.txt` file using `file_get_contents("entry.txt")`

Comment: That sounds perfect. I do have cPanel but I honestly wouldn't know how to set up the command for a cronjob, any advice? Thanks for this useful info, I tried upping this answer but it said my rep needs to be higher.

Comment: Ctrl+F for cron in cPanel.

Comment: lol. No I know where it is. I just wouldn't know how to write the actual command. No worries though, appreciate the help.